# Unable to implement the "OpenERP Arabic Report Support"

Tags: pdf, odoo, arabic, left-to-right

I'm running openERP 7, I was faced with the problem that Arabic words show up in pdf reports as black boxes. I tried to resolve this problem so I downloaded the code in the [OpenERP Arabic Report Support](https://github.com/barsi/openerp-rtl) and followed the instructions. When I copied the textobject.py to the path D:\OpenERP 7.0-20141026-011104\server\reportlab\pdfgen and tried to restart the openerp-server-7.0 service it does not start and gave me the following error, I got it from event viewer log for windows:

```html
The instance's SvcRun() method failed 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "win32serviceutil.pyo", line 835, in SvcRun
  File "win32_service.pyo", line 42, in SvcDoRun
SystemExit: 255 
%2: %3
```

and unable to continue. Can anyone check and help

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the latest python version 2.7.10 from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.10/python-2.7.10.msi
2. Install it and find the  mimetypes.pyc file from install path like C:\Python27\Lib
3. Copy the file and replace the same name file from openerp install path
   4.start the service again. try it out.